# Document Fragment loses contents after innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I read online, to prevent frequent reflows, and modifying the DOM every time we can use document fragments.So i took that approach and i wanted to populate 2 drop down with the same content (they actually contain years from 1990-2013).

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    var choice = document.createElement('option');
        choice.value = i;
        choice.innerHTML = i;
        fragment.appendChild(choice);
    }
$('#list').html(fragment);     //Populates #list with values 1-10
```

This works fine but, when i go to populate my 2nd drop down with same values, fragment now does not have any contents

```
$('#list2').html(fragment);    // Does not populate #list2
```

Demo JSFiddle : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantjani10/Nraq3/)

I tried an alternate approach too which works , what i want to know is how and why does document fragment loose contents after an innerHTML() ?

Comment: That's how `appendChild()` behaves. It moves the appended element instead of copying it. You need to clone or recreate the element before appending.

Comment: but if i create a var = "sample" and do a innerHTML at 3 DOM elements it retains the contents

Comment: You can try to use `cloneNode()` every time you append fragment in DOM. So instead of appending fragment itself, you append a clone from it.

Comment: Yes, you can assign `innerHTML` several times with the same variable, but when you use `appendChild(choise)`, `choise` will become `null`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in VBScript ? I am having an issue where it takes a lot of time to populate the objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what happens here is..the document fragment is created in memory and not in DOMtree so once you append the fragment.. it disappears... it is always better to use the clone of fragment created ..so  you can use the fragment created multiple times and actually, appending the clone ..

```
// fragment.cloneNode(true)
 $('#list').html(fragment.cloneNode(true));
 $('#list2').html(fragment.cloneNode(true));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nraq3/3/) here

[site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment) that might help

Answer (score 0):

[I think this should be done this way:](http://jsfiddle.net/Nraq3/1/)

```
$('#list2').html($('#list').children().clone());
```